# How to shut down cleanly on signal from UPS?

Tags: ups

Sp, our little Ubuntu server already killed a hard drive from a sudden power failure when the IPS wenr dead. The UPS sends a network signal to the LAN, but i don't know how to get Ubuntu to recognize the signal from the UPS?

Comment: Can you please detail the make and model of your UPS and, if possible, which piece of software you use on other computers to shut down on power failure? Computers don't magically "recognize" the signal from the UPS, they need software to act on it. As dobey points out, one alternative is `nut` but we can be more precise in our advice if you are more precise detailing your situation.

Comment: APC 2200. Do you need more than that? I'm currently disabled at home and can't physically view the devices. Sorry. I'm using logmein to a PC that has ultravnc to remote in to the server, so I can at least install/configure software. The other computers are all Windows Server, various iterations.

Comment: You could google for information on how to monitor that UPS on Linux. They seem to use SNMP, and nut has an snmp-ups module which you may be able to use. I also suggest you look at www.apc.com for more information, you can also request tech support for your hardware. UPS are not cheap and the onus is on the manufacturer to provide software to monitor it appropriately.

Comment: Take a look at APCUPSD and see if it will fill your needs http://www.apcupsd.org/

Answer (score 1):

Install and configure `nut-server` and `nut-client` to work with your UPS. Note that however, it does not work with all available UPS systems available.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a UPS (I have two APC 1400 units) you don't have to have LAN connection as the UPS should just kick in and maintain power, on mains failure it will (or should) sound a very audible alarm and mine will wake me even when I'm snoring in the next room.

One problem I often find is that a UPS unit is frequently loaded beyond it's capability. It is the cause of many headaches and crashes that using underrated supplies, causes spikes and voltage variations that are exactly what you are trying to avoid. Power failures often come with random pulses that will kill most drives unless the UPS is stable and working well within its limits ... are you sure yours are capable of handling at least 30% more than your system needs? My two main systems (750Watts max each) run off the two 1400VA units and the router runs on its own 350VA. This way it all stays alive.

Oh yeah, check the life of the batteries, they are definitely not immortal and even though they might take a full charge, they may not deliver anything like they did when new. The UPS only tells you a battery needs replacing when it is utterly dead, not nearly early enough!

Check with the UPS manufacturer's website for Linux specific LAN event power software, it will almost certainly be there as a free downland, as most servers run in Linux and UPS units are mostly in use on servers.

Comment: We have APC 2200. When this catastrophic failure occurred, everyone was in the building, but no one knew when the UPS would die completely.